# Как сделать фигуру прозрачной на bokeh python

Tags: python

Квадрат находится в круге. Нужно сделать так, чтобы круг был закрашен, в то время, как квадрат был прозрачен, причем в нем было бы видно фон графика. Рис 1. Каким инструментом для этого дела пользоваться?

[image: рис1]

Comment: По документации Fill properties:
fill_alpha
floating point between 0 (transparent) and 1 (opaque), fill_alpha=0 сделает квадрат прозрачным. <https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#fill-properties>

Comment: не совсем то что нужно, если я сделаю прозрачным внутренний квадрат, то будет видно цвет внешнего, а мне нужно чтоб был виден фон графика

Comment: Где тут круг на вашем рисунке и где график? Не очень понятно. Квадратный круг - ну, такое.

Answer (score 2):

В bokeh есть две фигуры с "дырками" p.multi_polygons и p.annulus. Надо аккуратно наложить их друг на друга(с одинаковы цветом), чтоб получить нужный рисунок.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import Range1d

output_file('multipolygon_with_holes.html')

p = figure(width=500, height=500, background_fill_color='blue')
p.multi_polygons(xs=[[[[1, 4, 4, 1], [2, 3, 3, 2]]]],
                 ys=[[[[1, 1, 4, 4], [2, 2, 3, 3]]]], color="orange")
p.annulus(x=[2.5], y=[2.5], inner_radius=1, outer_radius=2.5,
          color="orange")
p.x_range = Range1d(-0.5, 5.5)
p.y_range = Range1d(-0.5, 5.5)

show(p)
```

[image: шайба с квадратным отверстием]

[image: показано расположение фигур]

Comment: @CrazyElf
Добавил.